# codeigniter query to DB with multiple where

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I am unable to get request to DB in when passed variable to sql query is array like this:

```
$cl_phone = array(1,2,3);
```

Below model code

```
public function get_clients_enabled_array($cl_phones) {

        $this->db->order_by('filial_id');
        $this->db->order_by('client_name');
        $this->db->where('status','1');

            foreach ($cl_phones as $value) {

                $this->db->where('client_id',$value);
            }

        $query = $this->db->get('clients');

        return $query->result_array();

}
```

View display empty array `Array()`

What is the correct way?

Comment: Are you sure at the same time `client_id` column is equal to 1 ,2 and 3 ? I guess no you need `IN()` clause

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid it works! I thought where_in() must be used with `JOIN`

Comment: thats why i asked and guessed for the  values (1,2,3) that you need `IN()` clause not a loop with where

Comment: This happened because I did not know about `SELECT ... IN();` statement. See `https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html`

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `where_in` on client_id

Assuming your $cl_phones consist of only phone numbers, you can do something like this

```
$this->db->order_by('filial_id');
$this->db->order_by('client_name');
$this->db->where('status','1');

$this->db->where_in('client_id', $cl_phones); // Change here

$query = $this->db->get('clients');
return $query->result_array();
```

Also I believe you intend to use `where_in` on `client_phone` numbers and not on `client_id` (unless they are same)